# How to fit samples only to some of multiple outputs Keras Functional API

Tags: keras, neural-network

I am currently stuck with the problem of trying to fit a functional keras model with 10 outputs and one input with samples that each have assignments to the outputs.

Each sample has a list of 10 bools that indicate on which outputs this sample should be fitted.

My current Model looks like this:

```
        inputs = Input(shape=(self.state_count,))
        # create the layers that learn the gane
        d1 = Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1_shared",
                   kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=int(time.time())))(inputs)
        d2 = Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2_shared",
                   kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=None))(d1)
        # create the heads that come on top of the gamelayers
        models = []
        heads = []
        for i in range(head_count):
            name = "head_{}".format(i)
            head = Dense(self.action_count, activation='relu', name=name,
                         kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=None))(d2)
            heads.append(head)
            model = Model(input=inputs, output=head, name=("headmodel: {}".format(str(i))))
            model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
            models.append(model)
        total_model = Model(input=inputs, output=heads, name="overall_modell")
        total_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

i am looking for a way to pass a list of masks alongside with the trainingset of x and y so that  only heads indicated by the mask get fitted on the corresponding x and y.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following.

### Create head_masks for each head

```
inputs = Input(shape=(state_count,))
head_masks = [Input(shape=(n_labels,)) for _ in range(head_count)]
# create the layers that learn the gane
d1 = Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1_shared",
            kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=100))(inputs)
d2 = Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2_shared",
            kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=None))(d1)
# create the heads that come on top of the gamelayers
models = []
heads = []
for i in range(head_count):
    name = "head_{}".format(i)
    head = Dense(n_labels, activation='relu', name=name,
                  kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=None))(d2)
    heads.append(head*head_masks[i])

total_model = Model(inputs=[inputs,*head_masks], outputs=heads, name="overall_modell")
```

### Creating the inputs, targets and masks

This is using a toy dataset. I am creating a dataset of 25 elements. First, `samples` is the datapoints. Then I have a list of labels corresponding to each head (each label set is of size `25, state_count`).

Next I create the mask. Let's say I have a mask of size `(25, head_count)`. I need to do some manipulations to get this in correct shape. Ultimately, we need a list of (with `head_count` elements) as masks, where each mask is size `(25, n_labels)`. Then we mask any prediction and label which has mask value 0. This will result in gradients being zero. So there won't be any training for those samples and the corresponding heads.

```
samples = np.random.normal(size=(25, state_count))
labels = [np.random.choice([0,1], size=(25, n_labels)) for _ in range(head_count)]
fit_mask = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(25, head_count))
fit_mask = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(fit_mask, axis=-1), n_labels, axis=-1)
fit_masks = [m[:,0,:] for m in np.split(fit_mask, head_count, axis=1)]

total_model.fit([samples, *fit_masks], [l*m for l,m in zip(labels, fit_masks)])
```

Comment: @DanHae, glad it helped. If you're satisfied with the answer, please accept it.